# Use of symbol in Stata's xtline

Tags: stata

Is it possible to use a symbol with Stata's `xtline` command? I tried labeling the Y-axis, and it didn't work.

```
xtline decision, overlay t(weeknew) i(categnew1) scheme(sj) ytitle($\Pi$) xtitle(Week)
```

[image]

EDIT: so after a while, I was not able to find a code for Pi tilde. I had to insert it manually using an image editing app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
tw scatter price mpg, ytitle("`=ustrunescape("\u03C0\u0303\u2071")'{sub:nw}")
```

This combines the unicode character for the greek letter pi (\u03C0) with the tilde (\u0303), small i subscript (\u2071). We then convert escaped hex sequences to Unicode strings with the function. Unfortunately, while there is a small subscript n in Unicode, [there is no small subscript w](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf), so we will rely on Stata's subscripting capacity for that part.

You may also need to switch to a Unicode-friendly font, especially if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Documented e.g. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?text

You seem to be seeking

```
... ytitle({&Pi})
```

There is nothing specific to `xtline` here; this is generic across `graph`.

Comment: Nick, how about $Pi^i_{nw}$? It didn't seem to work with &.

Comment: I tried this: &Pi{sup:i}{sub:nw}, and it looks so ugly.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that LaTeX commands will work; that's incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I keep reminding myself that these are different programs, and the look will be different. Can Pi tilde work in Stata?

Comment: Tilde above the character that's to say, not a symbol on its own.